# Print all combinations of x objects in y slots (Java)

Tags: java, combinations

If you have x objects (can be represented by 1s) that are to be placed in y slots (empty slots can be represented as 0s), write a function that prints all of the possible ways that the objects can be placed in the slots.  The method will take as input the number of objects and the number of total slots.

For example, possibleCombinations(3, 5) should print the ways 3 objects can be placed in 5 slots:

11100, 11010, 11001, 10110, 10101, 10011, 01110, 01101, 01011, 00111

I've considered recursion as an option, but I'm not sure how to go about setting it up so that it works for any number of objects.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Here is some pseudo code, obviously I'm not using a very good data structure. But you can see each call if possible, checks the cases where each item is either included or not included and continues from there. That's the pair of recursive calls in the else statement.

```
func(a,b)
case 0,0
  return null;
case a>b
  return null;
else
  return {1,func(a-1,b-1)} & {0,func(a,b-1)};
```

Comment: Great! I was about to post something similiar:). Worth to add that it comes straight from the basic formula for computing combinations

Answer (score 2):

here is some java code:

```
public static void possibilities(int k,int n) {
    aux(k,n,new StringBuilder());
}
public static void aux(int k,int n,StringBuilder sb) {
    if (n == 0 && k == 0) {
        System.out.println(sb);
        return;
    } else if (n<k) {
        return;
    }
    if (k>0) { 
        aux(k-1,n-1,new StringBuilder(sb).append(1));
    }
    aux(k,n-1,new StringBuilder(sb).append(0));
}
```

aux() actually do the work, it does all possibilities: add 0 or add 1, and prints at the end only those who "used" all the possible 1's

**EDIT :** changed the recursion end condition, to trim cases that will not be printed at the end.

Answer (score 0):

That reminds me you can search `Permutations[Join[Table[1, {3}],Table[0, {5-3}]]]`, at [wolframalpha.com](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) and get the right answer.

Steps in this answer are:

- create set of 1's: 111
- create set of 0's: 00
- join them: 11100
- show all permutations:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I would do 3, 5. Start with the string `111`. 5 - 3 = 2, so adding 2 zeros total. There are four possible locations for each zero `a1b1c1d`. 4 ^ 2 means 16 possible locations, encoding the first location as 0 - 3, and second as (0 - 3) * 4. Now enumerate 0 - 15, and print out the resulting combination. In this scheme the first 5 outputs are:

```
00111, 01011, 01101, 01110, 01011
```

And we have a repeat. This mechanism is printing out permutations when you want combinations. There is likely a way to enumerate the combination but the simplest solution is to just index your results and ensure you don't return the same one twice.